# Echo was not working in php while loop

Tags: php

Updated Code Problem -----

```php
<?php
require "conn.php";
require "header.php";
if (isset($_GET["id"])) { // all the below code is happening only when $_GET["id"] is defined
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET["id"]); //
    $myid = $_SESSION["USER"]; //

    $image = "<img src='showimage.php?id=".$id." class='img-responsive img-circle margin' style='display:inline' alt='Bird' width='350' height='350'>";

    $query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE id='".$id."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $firstname = $row["firstname"];
        $lastname = $row["lastname"];
        $status = $row["status"];
        $bio = $row["bio"];
    }

    if ($id == $myid) {
        $centertext = "<center><font color='black'> You cannot add yourself as your friend</font></center>"; //echo this variable somewhere you want
    } else {
        $aquery = "SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user_id='$myid'";
        $aresult = mysqli_query($conn,$aquery);
        while ($arow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($aresult)) {
            $friend_id = $arow["friend_id"];
            $user_id = $arow["user_id"];
            $db_userid = $arow["id"];

            // Making a query for fetch friends data
            $bquery = "SELECT * FROM friends WHERE friend_id='$id'"; // make first ' then " then the variable and then " and ' this is for preventing sql-injections
            $bresult = mysqli_query($conn,$bquery);
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($bresult);
            if ($count !== 0) { // =! will not check if $count is not 0 you have to change it to !==
                $cquery = "SELECT * FROM friends"; // leave the '' out here, cause otherwise it's handled as a string, now its a int
                $cresult = mysqli_query($conn,$cquery);
                while ($crow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cresult)) {
                    $db_status = $crow["status"];
                    if ($db_status == 0) {
                        $statusAlreadySent = "Your friend request has already been sent";
                    } else {
                        $statusFriends = "You are friends";
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $noFriendsYet = "You have to send him friend request";
            }

        }
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Theme Made By www.w3schools.com - No Copyright -->
    <title>Profile</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            font: 20px Montserrat, sans-serif;
            line-height: 1.8;
            color: #f5f6f7;
        }
        p {font-size: 16px;}
        .margin {margin-bottom: 45px;}
        .bg-1 {
            background-color: #1abc9c; /* Green */
            color: #ffffff;
        }
        .bg-2 {
            background-color: #474e5d; /* Dark Blue */
            color: #ffffff;
        }
        .bg-3 {
            background-color: #ffffff; /* White */
            color: #555555;
        }
        .bg-4 {
            background-color: #2f2f2f; /* Black Gray */
            color: #fff;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid bg-1 text-center">
    <h3 class="margin"><?php if (isset($firstname)) {echo $firstname;} elseif (isset($lastname)) {echo $lastname;}  ?></h3>
    <?php
    if (isset($image)) {echo $image;} // maybe you have to change this to if (isset($image)) {$image;}
    ?>
    <h3 class="margin">Status: <?php echo "$status";  ?></h3> 
    <br>
</div>
<!--here comes the $centertext from above-->
<?php
if (isset($centertext)) {
  echo "$centertext";
}
if (isset($statusFriends)) {
    echo "$statusFriends";
}
if (isset($statusAlreadySent)) {
    echo "$statusAlreadySent";
}
if (isset($noFriendsYet)) {
    echo "<center>
    <form  method='post' action='profile.php?id=$id'>
    <input type='submit' value='Add $firstname as friend' class='btn btn-warning' name='addfriend'/>
    </form>
    </center>
    ";

}
 if (isset($_POST["addfriend"])) {
        $dquery = "INSERT INTO friends (user_id,friend_id,status) VALUES ('$myid','$id','0')";
        $dresult = mysqli_query($conn,$dquery);
        echo "Friend Request has sent";

    }

?>

<!-- Second Container -->
<div class="container-fluid bg-2 text-center">
    <h3 class="margin">About <?php if (isset($firstname)) {echo $firstname;} ?></h3>
    <p><?php if (isset($bio)) {echo $bio;};  ?></p>
</div>

<!-- Third Container (Grid) -->
<div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center">
    <h3 class="margin"> <?php if (isset($firstname)) {echo $firstname . " Friends";} ?></h3><br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <p></p>
            <img src="birds1.jpg" class="img-responsive margin" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Footer -->
<footer class="container-fluid bg-4 text-center">
    <p>FriendsLogin</p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

```php
<?php
require "conn.php";
require "header.php";
if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET["id"]);
  $myid = $_SESSION["USER"];
}

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <!-- Theme Made By www.w3schools.com - No Copyright -->
  <title>Profile</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  body {
      font: 20px Montserrat, sans-serif;
      line-height: 1.8;
      color: #f5f6f7;
  }
  p {font-size: 16px;}
  .margin {margin-bottom: 45px;}
  .bg-1 {
      background-color: #1abc9c; /* Green */
      color: #ffffff;
  }
  .bg-2 {
      background-color: #474e5d; /* Dark Blue */
      color: #ffffff;
  }
  .bg-3 {
      background-color: #ffffff; /* White */
      color: #555555;
  }
  .bg-4 {
      background-color: #2f2f2f; /* Black Gray */
      color: #fff;
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<?php  

$query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE id=$id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $firstname = $row["firstname"];
  $lastname = $row["lastname"];
  $status = $row["status"];
  $bio = $row["bio"];
}


?>
<div class="container-fluid bg-1 text-center">
 <h3 class="margin"><?php echo "$firstname $lastname"; ?></h3>
  <img src="showimage.php?id=<?php echo "$id"; ?>" class="img-responsive img-circle margin" style="display:inline" alt="Bird" width="350" height="350">
   <h3 class="margin">Status: <?php echo "$status"; ?></h3> <br>
</div>
<?php

if ($id == $myid) {
    echo "<center><font color='black'> You cannot add yourself as your friend</font></center>";
  } else {
    $aquery = "SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user_id='$myid'";
    $aresult = mysqli_query($conn,$aquery);
    while ($arow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($aresult)) {
      $friend_id = $arow["friend_id"];
      $user_id = $arow["user_id"];
      $db_userid = $arow["id"];

      // Making a query for fetch friends data
      $bquery = "SELECT * FROM friends WHERE friend_id='$id'";
      $bresult = mysqli_query($conn,$bquery);
      $count = mysqli_num_rows($bresult);
      if ($count =! 0) {
        $cquery = "SELECT * FROM friends WHERE status='1'";
        $cresult = mysqli_query($conn,$cquery);
        while ($crow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cresult)) {
          $status = $crow["status"];
          if ($status == 0) {
           echo "Your friend request has already been sent";
          } else {
             echo "You are friends";
          }
        }
      } else {
        echo "You have to send him friend request";
      }

  } 
}
?>

<!-- Second Container -->
<div class="container-fluid bg-2 text-center">
  <h3 class="margin">About <?php echo "$firstname"; ?></h3>
  <p><?php echo "$bio";  ?></p>
</div>

<!-- Third Container (Grid) -->
<div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center">
  <h3 class="margin"> <?php echo "$firstname friends";  ?></h3><br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <p></p>
      <img src="birds1.jpg" class="img-responsive margin" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Footer -->
<footer class="container-fluid bg-4 text-center">
  <p>FriendsLogin</p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Please help me What is the problem in this code? I am running it my localhost and it is not working.
So this is the user profile page where I am making to send friend request and friend request.

Comment: check your `}` in while loop

Comment: make all your php code before html

Comment: i'll correct that for you

Comment: But When you will do that

Comment: @VivekShukla 5min and i'll post an answer

Comment: @VivekShukla didn't expect that it'll last that long.. :P okay give me 2min

Comment: @VivekShukla now my answer is live :)

Comment: Okay I have to check that it is working or not

Answer (score 0):

now it should work with this code. i explained in comments the wrong parts:

```
<?php
require "conn.php";
require "header.php";
if (isset($_GET["id"])) { // all the below code is happening only when $_GET["id"] is defined
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_GET["id"]); //this won't protect you from sql injections...
    $myid = $_SESSION["USER"]; //

    $image = "<img src='showimage.php?id=".$id." class='img-responsive img-circle margin' style='display:inline' alt='Bird' width='350' height='350'>";

    $query = "SELECT * FROM register WHERE id='".$id."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $firstname = $row["firstname"];
        $lastname = $row["lastname"];
        $status = $row["status"];
        $bio = $row["bio"];
    }

    if ($id == $myid) {
        $centertext = "<center><font color='black'> You cannot add yourself as your friend</font></center>"; //echo this variable somewhere you want
    } else {
        $aquery = "SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user_id='".$myid."'";
        $aresult = mysqli_query($conn,$aquery);
        while ($arow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($aresult)) {
            $friend_id = $arow["friend_id"];
            $user_id = $arow["user_id"];
            $db_userid = $arow["id"];

            // Making a query for fetch friends data
            $bquery = "SELECT * FROM friends WHERE friend_id='".$id."'"; // make first ' then " then the variable and then " and ' this is for preventing sql-injections
            $bresult = mysqli_query($conn,$bquery);
            $count = mysqli_num_rows($bresult);
            if ($count !== 0) { // =! will not check if $count is not 0 you have to change it to !==
                $cquery = "SELECT * FROM friends WHERE status=1"; // leave the '' out here, cause otherwise it's handled as a string, now its a int
                $cresult = mysqli_query($conn,$cquery);
                while ($crow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($cresult)) {
                    $status = $crow["status"];
                    if ($status == 0) {
                        $statusAlreadySent = "Your friend request has already been sent";
                    } else {
                        $statusFriends = "You are friends";
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $noFriendsYet = "You have to send him friend request";
            }

        }
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Theme Made By www.w3schools.com - No Copyright -->
    <title>Profile</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        body {
            font: 20px Montserrat, sans-serif;
            line-height: 1.8;
            color: #f5f6f7;
        }
        p {font-size: 16px;}
        .margin {margin-bottom: 45px;}
        .bg-1 {
            background-color: #1abc9c; /* Green */
            color: #ffffff;
        }
        .bg-2 {
            background-color: #474e5d; /* Dark Blue */
            color: #ffffff;
        }
        .bg-3 {
            background-color: #ffffff; /* White */
            color: #555555;
        }
        .bg-4 {
            background-color: #2f2f2f; /* Black Gray */
            color: #fff;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container-fluid bg-1 text-center">
    <h3 class="margin"><?php if (isset($firstname)) {echo $firstname;} elseif (isset($lastname)) {echo $lastname;}  ?></h3>
    <?php
    if (isset($image)) {echo $image;} // maybe you have to change this to if (isset($image)) {$image;}
    ?>
    <h3 class="margin">Status: <?php if (isset($statusAlreadySent)) {echo $statusAlreadySent;} elseif (isset($statusFriends)) {echo $statusFriends;} elseif (isset($noFriendsYet)) {echo $noFriendsYet;} else {echo "No status"; }?></h3> 
    <br>
</div>
<!--here comes the $centertext from above-->
<?php
    if (isset($centertext)) {echo $centertext;};
?>

<!-- Second Container -->
<div class="container-fluid bg-2 text-center">
    <h3 class="margin">About <?php if (isset($firstname)) {echo $firstname;} ?></h3>
    <p><?php if (isset($bio)) {echo $bio;};  ?></p>
</div>

<!-- Third Container (Grid) -->
<div class="container-fluid bg-3 text-center">
    <h3 class="margin"> <?php if (isset($firstname)) {echo $firstname . "friends";} ?></h3><br>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <p></p>
            <img src="birds1.jpg" class="img-responsive margin" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Footer -->
<footer class="container-fluid bg-4 text-center">
    <p>FriendsLogin</p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is not working Actually When I echoed it then it was showing me You are friendsYour friend request has already been sent both at the same time.

Comment: can you post an image of your page? or have a live system where i can see it ?

Comment: Not now but tomorrow

Comment: @VivekShukla okay as you like... but tomorrow i'll have no time.. just deploy an image in your question and i'll have a look on it on friday

Comment: I added codes again you can see it is after { Updated code problem...} My database is like this id (which is auto incremented),user_id (user who sent friend request), friend_id (to whom he send friend request),status (0 indicate that friend request pending and 1 indicate that friend request has been accepted)